# List<Cluster<DoublePoint>> to Set<DoublePoint>

Tags: java, data-conversion, dbscan

I am trying to use DBSCANClusterer(apache.math3) to sort a Set of points which I generate and write it to a file. At this point, I am stuck here:

```
public Set<DoublePoint> DBSCAN(Set<DoublePoint> set2) { 
        Set<DoublePoint> points = new Set<DoublePoint>();
        DBSCANClusterer<DoublePoint> dbscan = new DBSCANClusterer<DoublePoint>(1, 15);
        //run dbscan on set of points
        List<Cluster<DoublePoint>> clusters = dbscan.cluster(set2);
        **sorted = clusters???**
```

How can I assign: `List<Cluster<DoublePoint>> clusters` to `Set<DoublePoint> sorted`?? I guess it should be something like 2D->1D!

And here is the rest of my code:

```
    import java.awt.Point;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import org.apache.commons.math3.ml.clustering.Cluster;
    import org.apache.commons.math3.ml.clustering.DBSCANClusterer;
    import org.apache.commons.math3.ml.clustering.DoublePoint;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Set;


public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Main().run(); 
    }

    public void run() {
        Set<DoublePoint> set = generateSetPoints();
        try {
            writeToFile(set, "points");
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception while writing to file");
        }

        Set<DoublePoint> set_by_dbscan = dbScan(set);//
        try {
            writeToFile(set_by_dbscan, "by_dbscan");
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception while writing to file"); 
        }

    }

    public Set<DoublePoint> generateSetPoints() { 
        int xx=100;
        int yy=100;
        Set<DoublePoint> set = new HashSet<>(); 
        Random rnd = new Random(); 
        int number=100;
        do{
            int tmp[] = new int[2];

            tmp[0] =   rnd.nextInt(xx); 
            tmp[1] =   rnd.nextInt(yy); 
            DoublePoint rndpoint    =   new DoublePoint(tmp);
            set.add(rndpoint);
        }
        while (set.size()<number);
        return set;
    }

    public void writeToFile(Set<DoublePoint> set, String filename) throws IOException { 
        File fout = new File( filename + ".txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

        for (DoublePoint p: set) {
            bw.write(p.getPoint()[0] + "," + p.getPoint()[1]);
            bw.newLine();
        }

        bw.close();
    }

    public Set<DoublePoint> dbScan(Set<DoublePoint> set2) { 
        Set<DoublePoint> points = new Set<DoublePoint>();
        DBSCANClusterer dbscan = new DBSCANClusterer(1, 15);
        List<Cluster<DoublePoint>> clusters = dbscan.cluster(set2);
        return clusters;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A HashSet is an *unsorted* data structure.

If you want `sorted` to be sorted, use something that retains order.

`sorted = nes HashSet<>()` is a real WTF...

Also, DBSCAN is not meant for sorting. Use OPTICS clustering instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, I should be using a TreeSet structure to retain order. Yeah, the sorted-unsorted names are wrong but I should be using DBScan to process the random generated points that I create, save and load from a file. I updated the original post to include all my code..any suggestions?

Comment: Note that it is DBSCAN, all uppercase. I still don't get what you want to 'sort'. DBSCAN does not sort.

Comment: By using DBSCAN, I would like to create clusters from the randomly generated points. Then save them in an output file and use them in GNUPLOT to visualize them. Can you help?

Comment: And where does sorting come in? I can't write the code for you. I don't use Apache, the ELKI version is much better. It has data generators and visualization, so you probably wouldn't need to write any further code.

Comment: Never mind the sorting, if you check I updated the names of my vars in the code provided. What I need help with is converting List<Cluster<DoublePoint>> to Set<DoublePoint>.

Comment: How would you get the clusters from the Set?